# How do I get affiliate to register using a valid id from previously registered affiliates

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I use Ultimate Affiliate Pro plugin to workout an affiliate system on my wordpress site.
I want prospective affiliates to use an ID from previously registered affiliates to register on the website as affiliate.
I tried adding a custom field (Referral ID) but there is no option for conditional statement to check if the entered ID exist in the Ultimate Affiliate Pro plugin.
Please how do I work this out?